# Событие при скролле

Tags: jquery

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
 var features = $('.features').offset().top;
 if($(this).scrollTop() > features) {
   $('.features').css('background-color','red');
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top-menu">
  <div class="logo"><a href="#"><span>New</span>Providence</a></div>
    <div class="burger-menu">
      <div class="burger-menu-top"></div>
      <div class="burger-menu-middle"></div>
      <div class="burger-menu-middle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu1 menu-hidden menu-visually-hidden">
      <span><a href="">Tour</a></span>
      <span><a href="#">Features</a></span>
      <span><a href="#">Pricing</a></span>
    </div>

    <div class="menu2 menu-hidden menu-visually-hidden">
      <span  class="help"><a href="#">Help</a></span>
      <span><a  href="#">Contacts</a></span>
      <span><button class=""><a href="#">Get  App</a></button></span>
    </div>
  </div>
     <div class="top-text">
      <h2>What happens tomorrow?</h2>
        <p>The sight of the tumblers restored Bob Sawyer to a degree of equanimity which he had not possessed since his interview with his landlady. His face brightened up, and he began to feel quite convivial.</p>
          <button class="flat-buttons watch-video">Watch video</button>
         </div>
        <div class="Iphone-6">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="layout">
    <div class="features">
      <div class="feature">
        <div class="feature-icon1"></div>
        <h2>Real-time all the time</h2>
        <p>Thus much I thought proper to tell you in relation to yourself,
        Thus much I thought proper to tell you in relation to yourself, and to the trust I reposed in you.</p>
        <p>Just then her head struck against the roof of the hall: in fact she was now more than nine feet high, and she at once took up the little golden key and hurried off to the garden door.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="feature">
        <div class="feature-icon2"></div>
        <h2>Adopt without any obstacles</h2>
        <p>This sounded a very good reason, and Alice was quite pleased to</p>
      <p>Just then her head struck against the roof of the hall: in fact she was 
        now more than nine feet high, and she at once took up the little golden key and hurried off to the garden door.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Сделал таким образом но есть некоторые ошибки.
1) Событие срабатывает на половине блока, а должен как только блок попадает в экран
2) При обновлении эфект не срабатывает пока не начнешь листать вниз или вверх
Как можно реализовать данные функции???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var features = $('.features').offset().top;
  if (features == 450) {
    $('.features').css('background-color', '#red');
  } else {
    $('.features').css('background-color', 'transparent');
  }
});
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var features = $('.features').offset().top;
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > features - 450) {
    $('.features').css('background-color', 'red');
  } else {
    $('.features').css('background-color', 'transparent');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top-menu">
  <div class="logo"><a href="#"><span>New</span>Providence</a></div>
  <div class="burger-menu">
    <div class="burger-menu-top"></div>
    <div class="burger-menu-middle"></div>
    <div class="burger-menu-middle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu1 menu-hidden menu-visually-hidden">
    <span><a href="">Tour</a></span>
    <span><a href="#">Features</a></span>
    <span><a href="#">Pricing</a></span>
  </div>

  <div class="menu2 menu-hidden menu-visually-hidden">
    <span class="help"><a href="#">Help</a></span>
    <span><a  href="#">Contacts</a></span>
    <span><button class=""><a href="#">Get  App</a></button></span>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="top-text">
  <h2>What happens tomorrow?</h2>
  <p>The sight of the tumblers restored Bob Sawyer to a degree of equanimity which he had not possessed since his interview with his landlady. His face brightened up, and he began to feel quite convivial.</p>
  <button class="flat-buttons watch-video">Watch video</button>

</div>
<div class="Iphone-6">
</div>
<div class="top-text">
  <h2>What happens tomorrow?</h2>
  <p>The sight of the tumblers restored Bob Sawyer to a degree of equanimity which he had not possessed since his interview with his landlady. His face brightened up, and he began to feel quite convivial.</p>
  <button class="flat-buttons watch-video">Watch video</button>

</div>
<div class="Iphone-6">
</div>
<div class="top-text">
  <h2>What happens tomorrow?</h2>
  <p>The sight of the tumblers restored Bob Sawyer to a degree of equanimity which he had not possessed since his interview with his landlady. His face brightened up, and he began to feel quite convivial.</p>
  <button class="flat-buttons watch-video">Watch video</button>

</div>
<div class="Iphone-6">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="layout">
  <div class="features">
    <div class="feature">
      <div class="feature-icon1"></div>
      <h2>Real-time all the time</h2>
      <p>Thus much I thought proper to tell you in relation to yourself, Thus much I thought proper to tell you in relation to yourself, and to the trust I reposed in you.</p>
      <p>Just then her head struck against the roof of the hall: in fact she was now more than nine feet high, and she at once took up the little golden key and hurried off to the garden door.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="feature">
      <div class="feature-icon2"></div>
      <h2>Adopt without any obstacles</h2>
      <p>This sounded a very good reason, and Alice was quite pleased to</p>
      <p>Just then her head struck against the roof of the hall: in fact she was now more than nine feet high, and she at once took up the little golden key and hurried off to the garden door.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="top-text">
    <h2>What happens tomorrow?</h2>
    <p>The sight of the tumblers restored Bob Sawyer to a degree of equanimity which he had not possessed since his interview with his landlady. His face brightened up, and he began to feel quite convivial.</p>
    <button class="flat-buttons watch-video">Watch video</button>
    <div class="top-text">
      <h2>What happens tomorrow?</h2>
      <p>The sight of the tumblers restored Bob Sawyer to a degree of equanimity which he had not possessed since his interview with his landlady. His face brightened up, and he began to feel quite convivial.</p>
      <button class="flat-buttons watch-video">Watch video</button>
      <div class="top-text">
        <h2>What happens tomorrow?</h2>
        <p>The sight of the tumblers restored Bob Sawyer to a degree of equanimity which he had not possessed since his interview with his landlady. His face brightened up, and he began to feel quite convivial.</p>
        <button class="flat-buttons watch-video">Watch video</button>

      </div>
```

Comment: $(this).scrollTop() > features - 450 // вместо 450 нужно подставить высоту блока

Comment: но остается проблема, при перезагрузке страницы ничего не выполняется если не сдвинуть скролл

Comment: обновил код, должно работать